# Accessing Netgear router DG834GU

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

I've got an old Netgear router model DG834GU whose settings I'd like to change.  We've got a working internet connection through this router (the router itself is connected to another router).  But for some reason I fail to access the router to change settings (name, password, etc.).

I tried several things, as suggested by [How do I log in to my NETGEAR home router?](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/980/~/how-do-i-log-in-to-my-netgear-home-router%3F?cid=wmt_netgear_organic) or [Unable to access the router web interface: Router login page cannot be displayed or is blank](https://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/27199?cid=wmt_netgear_organic).

That is, I tried to connect to open www.routerlogin.net, www.routerlogin.com, http://192.168.0.1, and http://192.168.1.1. The first two websites resulted in the strange error message

> You are not connected to your Router’s WiFi network. To access routerlogin.com, your device must be connected to your Router’s WiFi network. Check your current connection and try again.

Of course this is not true, because I can access internet through this very network.

I tried all the above with and without cable, through an Android Smartphone, Windows 7 and Ubuntu 14.04.  What else can I do to speak to my router?

Comment: There may be other protocoles than http. To check which services your router support in Linux, install nmap and run `nmap -p- 192.168.1.1` and try `telnet 192.168.1.1` if the telnet port is open.

Comment: try the HTTPS versions of those links.

Comment: Any try different browsers ...

Comment: @DavidPostill: I tried Chrome and Firefox

Comment: @FrankThomas: No effect: The ip version sites are loading forever, while for the other two Firefox says the connection is not secure

Comment: Try resetting the router.

Comment: @VBF: Following is the output:`Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.06 seconds`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably need to use the wired connection and connect our computer directly to the router. That's how a specialist managed my Netgear modem many years ago.

Of course you'll need to make sure your password and username are correct too.

When you're connecting directly using the wired connection, make sure wireless is turned off on the computer as well, and you may also want to disconnect any other wired connections to the router.

The manual for the router may be helpful to have as well. Here's the link:
http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/DG834GV5/DG834Gv5_SM_31Mar08.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same error message on my new Netgear Nighthawk X6 R8000 router.  I used curl to see what the router was returning.  The problem appears to be that the page returned by the router redirects to "www.routerlogin.net" (even when you specify 198.168.1.1 for the address), but I got the global DNS response for this host instead of the router's IP because of DNScrypt on my Ubuntu machine and some corporate DNS override on my Mac.  Adding this line to my /etc/hosts file fixed the problem for me on Mac and Ubuntu:

```
192.168.1.1     routerlogin.net www.routerlogin.net
```

Make sure to use the LAN IP address specified in your router's instructions.  If you change the router's LAN IP address, do not forget to update this entry in /etc/hosts to keep accessing the router through your browser after reboot.